# How to use functions in Oriento Query Builder where clauses?

Tags: node.js, orientdb, oriento

How do I write following example from the OrientDB docs using the Oriento Query Builder (part of Oriento the OrientDB driver for node.js)?

```
select name.toLowerCase() == 'luke' from Actors
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.select().from('Actors').where('name.toLowerCase() = :name').addParam('name', 'luke').all();
```